# How to get google search counter?

Tags: android

When I type a keyword like "Doing Homework"+"having class", google would return "About 4,360 results".
I tried to fetch a webpage but it spent too much time to read and search the source code.

Could google return a XML file?

or

How can I get the counter quickly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Google API but you are limited to 100 queries a day or something or that sort.

http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html